# Making changes to a props array passed down from parent component in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need to make changes to an array of nested objects from a child component. The array was passed down as props from a parent component and I want to find a item on the list and make a change to it, so that when I go back to the parent scene the changes will be saved. I have the following code, but I get this error: `undefined is not an object (evaluating \'this.state')`. Can anybody lead me in the right direction troubleshooting this?

```
submitChange() {
  //update the cart list
  //hide the panel
  this.props.cartList.forEach(function(arrayItem) {
    if(arrayItem.prod.product === this.state.name) {
      arrayItem.quantityOrdered = this.state.quantity;
    }
    console.log(arrayItem.prod.product + " " + arrayItem.quantityOrdered)
  })
  console.log( " this item" + this.state.quantity + ", " + this.state.name)
  //this.props.hidePanel()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about React-Native, but in React you would have

**Parent Component**

```
getInitialState: function(){
    var carList = [.....];
 },

 changeCarItem: function(item){
    //first get the original 
    //find the item you want to modify 
    //after the item is found, make the change to your originalItem(carlist)
    //you need to use **this.setState()**, in-order to affect the main data
 }

 render: function(){
    <Child list={this.state.carList} changeCarItem={this.changeCarItem}>
    ......
 }
```

**Child Component**

```
//perform your logic
//use this.props.changeCarItem(item)
```

So to summarize, you need to pass a callback from the parent, in this case
"changeCarItem" and make the child component call this callback.

(http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html), have a look at this